# Reusing Visual Studio Debugging Visualizers

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, envdte

I am developing a Visual Studio Add-in where one of the controls is a settings editor similar to the locals or watch window. Because strings are one of the data types being displayed/supported in this control, I would like to add a text visualizer similar to Visual Studio's baked in visualizers for debugging. I have provided a picture below to illustrate exactly what I'm referring to:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIa1z.jpg

Am I on my own, or is there a way to reuse the existing Visual Studio debugging visualizers in my project?

thanks :)

Comment: NB For the visualizers I've written, I use a specific [solution structure](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer/wiki/Solution-structure) that allows exposing and reusing the UI elements of the visualizer as a NuGet package.

Answer (score 2):

These visualizers appear to be tightly coupled to Visual Studio and are not available via any command or interface. If anybody discovers otherwise, I'd love to know :)